# R3.6.3 finreportr error while getting financial data from edgar

Tags: r, finance

I am using `rstudio Version 1.2.1335`.
I updated all my package using rstudio.  So everything should be updated.

The strange thing was it was working for me a few hours ago when I was using R 3.6.0.  Then it stopped working.  Then I updated my `R` to `3.6.3`  just now, but still not working.  It either gives me an error or it will be running for so long I have to alt+ctrl+del to quit rstudio.

`companyinfo()` works
but `getbalancesheet`, `getincome`, `getcashflow`  do not work. Anyone know why?  Thank you.

I received the following error, which seems to has an impossible URL, don't know why and how can I fix it?:

```
GetBalanceSheet("SQ",2019)  (SQ is the company Square inc)

> Error in fileFromCache(file) :    Error in download.file(file,
> cached.file, quiet = !verbose) :    cannot open URL
> 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1512673/000151267319000003/https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2018/dei-2018-01-31.xsd'
> 
> In addition: Warning message: In download.file(file, cached.file,
> quiet = !verbose) :   cannot open URL
> 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1512673/000151267319000003/https://xbrl.sec.gov/dei/2018/dei-2018-01-31.xsd':
> HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

Thank you for the reply.  I tried GetBalanceSheet("FB", 2019),  it gives me a similar error.  I think the URL it is showing in the error message suggest the function is trying to open an invalid URL.

```
Below is my session info

R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 16299)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] finreportr_1.0.1 edgar_2.0.2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1        rstudioapi_0.11   knitr_1.28        xml2_1.2.5       
 [5] magrittr_1.5      tidyselect_1.0.0  tm_0.7-7          R6_2.4.1         
 [9] rlang_0.4.5       stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_0.8.5       tools_3.6.3      
[13] parallel_3.6.3    xfun_0.12         R.oo_1.23.0       assertthat_0.2.1 
[17] tibble_2.1.3      crayon_1.3.4      NLP_0.2-0         purrr_0.3.3      
[21] R.utils_2.9.2     curl_4.3          glue_1.3.2        slam_0.1-47      
[25] qdapRegex_0.7.2   stringi_1.4.6     compiler_3.6.3    pillar_1.4.3     
[29] R.methodsS3_1.8.0 XML_3.99-0.3      pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Update
I found that if I use a VPN....then the function work...is SEC blocking my IP??? is the even possible?

Comment: What is your ```finreportr``` version?

Comment: Please add ```sessionInfo()``` details to your question.

Comment: Which company code is `SQ`, I tried the same with `FB` and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Pragyaditya Das.  I have updated the post with the info you asked.  SQ is Square, Inc, a payment company